# Get the Path from a filename

Tags: c#, file, path

So I have a file(e.g. index.html) and I want to get the Path of it.
Most of my files are stored in the debug- folder. 
So e.g. I wanna get the Path :

C:\documents and settings\administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebServer\WebServer\bin\Debug\index.html

I already tried Path.GetDirectoryname(filename); //doesn't work because I don't get anything back

Comment: Do you want to search all harddrives/network folders for all files names index.html, or do you have a reference to it somewhere? Or do you only want to search in the folder where your exe runs?

Comment: `string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\index.html";`

Comment: The answer from John Woo works for me, Thanks for the fast answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Path.GetFullPath(fileName);
```

- [**SOURCE**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx)

Comment: you're welcome @Lola. don't know why my answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably searching for [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

> The MapPath method maps the specified relative or virtual path to the
>   corresponding physical directory on the server.

From the name of the file and *expected* result I deduct that you're asking for `ASP.NET`.

Comment: no it was nothing server related. I just wanted to know the FullPath from the File that I have (the file which the Client requested). The Answer from John Woo works for me. But thanks for you help